# Finding the rule of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I have a linear transformation $f: V^2\rightarrow V^2$. All I know is this $f (1, 0)=(2, 1)$ and $f (1, 1)=(3, -1)$ but I don't know the rule of this transformation. I am supposed to find the matrix, but I am not really sure how to do this without knowing the rule.

I have tried forming the matrices of these vectors and than using some matrix operations to find the needed matrix but I don't get the same answer as in the solution.

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that$(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)$.

Using the fact that $f$ is linear we have $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$. Thus we note that

$$(3,-1)=f(1,1)=f((1,0)+(0,1))=f(1,0)+f(0,1)=(2,1)+f(0,1)$$
$$\implies f(0,1)=(1,-2)$$

We can see that the matrix associated to $f$ is
$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 \\
        1 & -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

In fact if $x=(0,1)^T$, $y=(1,0)^T$ we have $f(x)=Ax=(1,-2)$ and $f(y)=Ay=(2,1)$

Comment: I also get that solution, but my textbook says otherwise. The solution there is $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 // 2 & -3 // \end{pmatrix}. Is it possible that the textbook solution is wrong? I am really confused since you and I both got the same solution which appears to be wrong, using different approaches.